# What is difference between selecting users.* and selecting each individual columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, join, include, distinct

I'm working on studying Ruby on Rails, and have some specific questions about rails active records and their SQL conversions.

FYI, I'm using postgresql, and *user* model has many *statuses*, and I wanted to order *users* based on *created_at* column of *statuses*. Although I found out the solution, `User.includes(:statuses).order('statuses.created_at desc')`, I still have some (maybe inter-related) things I don't understand well.

1) On rails console, (I simplified for better readibility)

`User.joins(:statuses).to_sql` produces `"SELECT users.* FROM users INNER JOIN statuses ON statuses.user_id = users.id"`.

`User.includes(:statuses).references(:statuses).to_sql` produces `"SELECT users.id AS t0_r0, ...(simplified)... statuses.created_at AS t1_r3 FROM users LEFT OUTER JOIN statuses ON statuses.user_id = users.id"`

**What is difference between selecting users.* and selecting each individual columns?**

2) Also on rails console,

`User.joins(:statuses).size` produces `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users INNER JOIN statuses ON statuses.user_id = users.id => 155`.

`User.includes(:statuses).references(:statuses).size`  produces `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT users.id) FROM users LEFT OUTER JOIN statuses ON statuses.user_id = users.id => 16`.

**Why *includes* automatically contains *distinct* clause while *joins* does not?**

3) I tried to obtain distinct *users* ordered by *statuses.created_at*, with *statuses* joined on *users*.

I used this clause: `User.joins(:statuses).select('users.*, statuses.created_at').order('statuses.created_at desc').distinct`. (I should use *select statuses.created_at* due to `PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list`)

But this clause doesn't remove duplication! Although `User.joins(:statuses).select!('users.*, statuses.created_at').order('statuses.created_at desc').distinct.size` produces *16*, when I actually execute it, I see a lot of duplications.

It produces SQL statement: `SELECT DISTINCT users.*, statuses.created_at FROM users INNER JOIN statuses ON statuses.user_id = users.id ORDER BY statuses.created_at desc`, and it shows the following image.

[Result of User.joins(:statuses).select!('users.*, statuses.created_at').order('statuses.created_at desc').distinct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIAnw.png)

As you see, it shows duplications of my records.

So my third question is, **why distinct clause doesn't remove duplications (and why *size* shows distinct result)?**

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `joins` method just generates a SQL join for you. Any individual user may be joined to multiple statuses - that's just what joins do, if this isn't what you need then it's up to you to deal with it. The select clause defaults to `users.*` so that you don't unwittingly end up with identically named columns across both tables shadowing each other (eg the `id` column)

`includes` on the other hand is for eager loading an association. That this is sometimes accomplished with a join is just an inplementation detail - there is extra code in the handling of the result so that the result set features each user exactly once (and with the status data fed into the association). Includes also aliases all the column names to handle identically named columns

Lastly your distinct clause isn't removing duplicates because the rows aren't identical - the `statuses.created_at` column is included, which will be different across most rows.

The `size` method ignores your select clause and so counts against `users.id` - in that case distinct will only count each user once

Comment: I signed in to Stackoverflow to ask a question, and realized there is a question I asked 3 years ago. Although it's very late, thanks @Frederick for your sincere response.